# How can I bundle distance values with an array of coordinates (python)?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, scipy, jupyter-notebook

Edited to include my code. Learning python so please excuse me if I'm missing something basic here. I've written a code which identifies the coordinates of the local maxima of a distance transform array (source image can be found here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vFWp.jpg):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import img_as_float


img2 = cv2.imread('test4.jpg')
distance = cv2.distanceTransform(img2, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=0, dstType=cv2.CV_8U)
#plt.imshow(distance)
cv2.imwrite('distance1.jpg',distance)

im = img_as_float(distance)
image_max = ndi.maximum_filter(im, size=40, mode='constant')

for sigma in range(4):
    coordinates = peak_local_max(ndi.gaussian_filter(im,sigma=sigma), min_distance=40)
    print(f"Sigma for smoothing{sigma}, coordinates of peaks:")
    print(coordinates)
```

Here is an example output of the coordinate array:

```
[[ 600  368]
 [ 549 2060]
 [ 545  553]
 [ 483 1583]
 [ 464  351]
 [ 401  491]
 [ 346  655]
 [ 338 1484]
 [ 306  740]
 [ 303 1820]
 [ 219  929]
 [ 113 1174]]
```

All I need to do is compile the actual values from the distance transform array at each of these XY coordinates into an array or matrix from which I can calculate an average and standard deviation. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your code.  How did you generate these coordinates?  To find the maxima, you must have a way to map a coordinate toe a distance value.

Comment: Updated to add my code.

Comment: The distance value for coordinate (600,368) is `im[368][600]`.  That should be enough to get your data.  I don't think you need `img_as_float`; the `distance` matrix is already float32.